# Minor confusion about triple for loop one-in-another-in-another

Tags: c

The language is C.

The point of the program is to scan a matrix `[5][10]` and find the columns in which the biggest number in the column equals the sum of elements of the column to the left of the before-said column.

Take for example http://prntscr.com/hdzc5t: Here we can see that the biggest number in column 1 is 17 which is equal to the sum of all numbers in column 0, so the program prints out the index "1".

So I wrote two code snippets. The first one works and the second one doesn't, and there's only a minor difference (literally I changed the places of two characters) and I can't fathom why don't both of them function.

code 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)  {
    int i, j, W, suma[10] = {0}, NBR[10];

    int  array[5][10] = {   {1, 2, 5, 2, 7, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1},
                            {4, -8, 7, 3, 5, 3, 15, 0, 3, 0},
                            {7, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1},
                            {2, 17, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5},
                            {3, -5, 3, 6, -1, 5, 1, 6, 1, 10}};

    for(j = 0; j < 10; ++j){
        for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
           suma[j] += array[i][j];
           for (W = 0; W < 5; ++W){
            if(array[W][j] > array[i][j])
                NBR[j] = array[W][j];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Indeksi stupaca:\n");
    for(j = 1; j < 10; ++j){
        if (NBR[j] == suma[j-1])
            printf ("%d\n", j);
    }

    printf("Polje:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < 10; ++j){
            printf ("%5d", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

code 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)  {
    int i, j, W, suma[10] = {0}, NBR[10];

    int  array[5][10] = {   {1, 2, 5, 2, 7, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1},
                            {4, -8, 7, 3, 5, 3, 15, 0, 3, 0},
                            {7, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1},
                            {2, 17, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5},
                            {3, -5, 3, 6, -1, 5, 1, 6, 1, 10}};

    for(j = 0; j < 10; ++j){
        for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
           suma[j] += array[i][j];
           for (W = 0; W < 5; ++W){
            if(array[i][j] > array[W][j])
                NBR[j] = array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Indeksi stupaca:\n");
    for(j = 1; j < 10; ++j){
        if (NBR[j] == suma[j-1])
            printf ("%d\n", j);
    }

    printf("Polje:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < 10; ++j){
            printf ("%5d", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The first snippet works, but the second snippet doesn't work and I just can't get it into my head why. The loop goes through all the j, i and W possibilities in either code, but the second code just refuses to give back proper results. Thanks whoever gets it right.

This is the part that gets a bit modified and causes problems:

```
if(array[W][j] > array[i][j])
    NBR[j] = array[W][j];
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: okay did the debugger, it produced an .exe file and returns exactly the same, (partially) correct answer. It produes only 1 correct solution, out of the 3 that should be and that are produced by code 1

Comment: A debugger doesn't produce an exe. A debugger lets you step through the code and inspect variables as you go. Perhaps try adding some `printf()s` so you can trace the flow and see some variables.

Comment: It might be easier to just paste in the entire code once, and write a comment pointing to the line you changed.  This is like looking for a needle in a haystack. EDIT: Oh I see you did that at the very end, but I can't seem to delete this comment.

Comment: Both code snippets produce wrong NBR-s. 'printf' them to see for yourself. Then grab pen and paper and trace how these values evolve (concentrate only on one of the wrong columns) and you should relatively easily figure out why they don't end up with the desired maximums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually neither works, it was just luck.  When you set `NBR[j]`, the max number in the column, you are only ever comparing 2 numbers from the column at a time.  This is bound to miss some.  What you need to do is write this, instead of the nested loops:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    suma[j] += array[i][j];
    if (i == 0 || array[i][j] > NBR[j]) {
        NBR[j] = array[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: okay thanks a lot now I get it - still not sure why my starting idea did not work but this is definitely a faster and more compact solution with less variables :D

need to keep in mind to always set a logical starting point which is then compared to other characters in an array or w/e

Answer (score 0):

@jcarpenter2 is right. But for your lucky case if you look closely to mentioned two lines

```
for (W = 0; W < 5; ++W){
    if(array[i][j] > array[W][j])
        NBR[j] = array[i][j];
}
```

You are comparing only top element array[i][j] of the column with rest of the elements of the column, if first one is > than others, then only you are updating NBR[j]